# Postgres Alter Column Integer to Boolean

Tags: database, postgresql

I've a field that is INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 and I need to change that to bool.

This is what I am using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytabe 
ALTER mycolumn TYPE bool 
USING 
    CASE 
        WHEN 0 THEN FALSE 
        ELSE TRUE 
    END;
```

But I am getting:

```
ERROR:  argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type integer

********** Error **********

ERROR: argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type integer
SQL state: 42804
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER mycolumn TYPE bool USING CASE WHEN mycolumn=0 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END;
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER COLUMN mycolumn SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

You need to remove the constraint first (as its not a boolean), and secondly your `CASE` statement was syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 16):

Postgres can automatically cast integer to boolean. The key phrase is

```
using some_col_name::boolean
-- here some_col_name is the column you want to do type change
```

Above Answer is correct that helped me Just one modification instead of case I used type casting

```
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER mycolumn TYPE bool USING mycolumn::boolean;
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER COLUMN mycolumn SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Comment: The Accepted answer is better because it does *not* rely on type-casting. This method fails with `cannot cast type smallint to boolean`, for example.

Comment: @BenJohnson try `USING mycolumn::text::boolean;`

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you don't have any CHECK constraint on you column like:

`[...] CONSTRAINT blabla CHECK ((field = ANY (ARRAY[0, 1])))`

otherwise you alter command will error with a `cannot convert to boolean type`