# cant store 0 or 1 as boolean laravel postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I was able to store boolean values as 0 or 1 , but suddenly it keeps returning me the error

```
column \"trial\" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
```

Im using postgresql 13 with laravel 8

how can I solve this ?

Comment: Show your model and your table

Comment: @AhmedRafie, php-pgsql has updated on my system, and this problem happened to all my Laravel-Postgres projects

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81002

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED

after a lot of searching here and there , I found a query to update the pg_cast to allow 0 and 1 as boolean

```
update pg_cast set castcontext='a' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are on PHP 7.4.18 or 8.0.5 then watch for a breaking change:

From [Github PHP #6801](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6801#issuecomment-828783810):

> In summary, previously if you had a boolean column on a Postgres
> table, you could bind an integer value (0 or 1 typically) in the where
> condition against that column using PDO::PARAM_INT and everything was
> fine. However, you will now receive an error.

While the fix was already reverted, we need to downgrade to 7.4.16 / 8.0.3 or wait for the next patch release. See [PHP Issue #80892](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80892)

Comment: This is pretty crazy. I hit this bug silently through my Docker build process, and was very confused upon reading the CI failures as to why this would be happening. I thought I was being conservative enough specifying `php:8.0-alpine` in my Docker image, but clearly not.

Disappointing this wasn't caught before release.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure about your model because you did not share it... If you [**READ THE DOCUMENTATION**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) you will find out that you can `cast` a value.

So, your model should have a property `$casts` like this:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'trial' => 'boolean'
];
```

This will allow you to input any value and it will always cast it back to boolean so you can do `$model->trial = 1`, or `$model->trial = '1'` or `$model->trial = 2` or any `true`-ish value and it will cast it to `true`, so you should not have any more problems...

Same goes for `false`-ish values like `0` or `null`, etc.

Comment: I was able to insert 0 and 1 without specifying the $casts for a long time , I dont know whats new in the case to prevent that ?

Comment: What did you update ? We cannot know anything if we do not know what have you done for this to happen... did you change your database like MySQL to PostgreSQL ? Did you update Laravel to 8 ? Did you run a new migration ? What were you running before this started to happen ?

Comment: I can doubt about the upgrade I did to laravel from 5.8 to 8 , but it was working fine for at least 4 days since that .

Comment: Are you working with someone else ? I mean, using a VCS like Git so he/she could have changed the code ? Can you share any data like that ? This is not magic that you update and works for X amount of time and then does not, something happened in the middle. Maybe PostgreSQL got updated ?

Comment: Im using docker image version 13 for postgresql , can it be updated after restarting docker-compose ?

Comment: No, you must rebuild it to get it updated (only if you are doing `docker-compose up -d --build` or you down the image and then up again). Also, you have to be using `image: postgres:latest` for this to happen, if you are using a tag version, should be no problem then. Or you go inside the running container and manually update it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this. It's worked for me.

`'pgsql'` => [
  `'driver'` => `'pgsql'`,
  `'url'` => env(`'DATABASE_URL'`),
  `'host'` => env(`'DB_HOST'`, `'127.0.0.1'`),
  `'port'` => env(`'DB_PORT'`, `'5432'`),
  `'database'` => env(`'DB_DATABASE'`, `'forge'`),
  `'username'` => env(`'DB_USERNAME'`, `'forge'`),
  `'password'` => env(`'DB_PASSWORD'`, `''`),
  `'charset'` => `'utf8'`,
  `'prefix'` => `'tbt_'`,
  `'prefix_indexes'` => true,
  `'schema'` => `'public'`,
  `'sslmode'` => `'prefer'`,
  `'options'` => extension_loaded(`'pdo_pgsql'`) ? array_filter([
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
  ]) : [],
  ],

Answer (score -2):

As far as I remember, you could store int in a bool column in postgres, I tried it on my several projects. Maybe you need  to alter your `trial` column using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN trial DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER trial TYPE bool USING CASE WHEN trial=0 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN trial SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN trial DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER trial TYPE bool USING trial::boolean;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN trial SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740303/postgres-alter-column-integer-to-boolean)

another way is just convert integer to boolean using php:

```
$t = 1;
$f = 0;
$b = !!t; //true
$a = !!f; //false
```

Comment: Since this is laravel related questions, probably the op doesn't use direct sql to create the tables but migrations.

Comment: We can use RAW SQL query in the migration.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787293/run-raw-sql-in-migration

Comment: For sure, but we can also nou use it. That's advantage of the schema builder

Comment: schema builder doesn't support `using case`